# ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes: $filepath = "D:\20201124131044\ITRACS-20201124034849\"

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run a playbook that sends out an email with attachments if and only if the attachments are present. The powershell script works perfect, i tested it out. However, when I try to implement the same logic into ansible it fails. My code:

```
tasks:        
    - name: Send Email Notification
      win_shell: |
        $filepath = "D:\20201124131044\ITRACS-20201124034849\"
        $files    = 'error.log','environment.log','TRACS-20201124034849.sterr.stdout'
        $attachments = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $filepath -File | Where-Object { $files -contains $_.Name })
         
         
        if ($attachments.Count) {
            $Password     = "{{ansible_pass}}"
            $mypassword   = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
            $mycredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("{{ansible_user}}", $mypassword)

            $mailParams = @{
                To          = "{{Email}}"
                From        = "xxxxxx"
                Subject     = "test"
                Body        = "test"
                Credential  = $mycredential
                Attachments = $attachments.FullName
                SmtpServer  = "xxxxxx"

          }
          Send-MailMessage @mailParams
        }
        else {
            Write-Host 'Nothing to send..' 
        }
```

The error I am seeing:

```
ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes: $filepath = "D:\TRACS-20201124034849\"
```

I tried fixing the indentations - that didnt work. I tried commenting out attachments - that didnt work. Please advise.

UPDATE

the problem seems to be the \ at the end of the `$filepath = D:\20201124131044\ITRACS-20201124034849\`

Comment: Your update means you don't have any problem, because 849\ and 849 refer to the same directory, so you can omit the trailing backslash and your problem is over. I believe PowerShell is also bright enough to understand `"D:/thing/other/thing"` style paths, which could also make this problem go away

Answer (score 0):

The error was with the filepath which was fixed by eliminating the backslash at the end